# Error: no hace Update el valor correcto y solo hace update al primer valor de la lista en la tabla

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo una tabla `Cuentas` con la lista de nombres:

```
idCuenta Nombre
1        cuenta1
2        cuenta2
```

Mi codigo muestra la lista de Cuentas en un menu desplegable

```
    @if ($Cuentas->count())
    @foreach($Cuentas->where('idCuentas', $UsuarioDeCuentas->idCuentaU) as $CuentasHeaderList)

    <li>

    <a class="dropdown-item"   <--- la clase que muestra el menu
       onclick="event.preventDefault();    <--- al hacer click submit
       document.getElementById('CuentasHeaderListUpdateForm').submit();">
       {{$CuentasHeaderList->nombre}} <--- el valor que quiero guardar                         
    </a>

<form id="CuentasHeaderListUpdateForm" 
      action="{{route('CuentasHeaderListUpdate', Auth::user()->id)}}" 
      method="POST" 
      style="display: none;"> <--- este es el form dentro de mi menu desplegable donde asigno la ruta y id del usuario 

        @method('PATCH') <-- tipo de metodo y token de segurida
        @csrf

<input type="hidden" name="ultima_cuenta" value="{{$CuentasHeaderList->nombre}}"/>


</form>
    </li>

    @endforeach
    @endif
```

esta es mi ruta :

```
Route::PATCH('/CuentasHeaderListUpdate/{id}', 'HomeController@CuentasHeaderListUpdate')->name('CuentasHeaderListUpdate');
```

este es mi controlador :

```
//cuenta
    public function CuentasHeaderListUpdate(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
         'ultima_cuenta' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);  <--- encierro en una variable los nombres (con algo de validacion)
        Users::where('id',$id)->update($validatedData); <-- hago el update segun id 
        return redirect('home');<--- y regreso a mi pagina 
    }
```

Mi problema es que sin importar la opción que elija en el `<select>` siempre manda el valor de hasta arriba cuenta1 , lo cual no entiendo `$CuentasHeaderList->nombre` esta dentro de la logica que le dice el valor es 1 o 2

Comment: tienes el form con `id="CuentasHeaderListUpdateForm"` dentro del foreach, o sea muchos forms con `id="CuentasHeaderListUpdateForm"`, cuando haces click en el enlace y seleccionas el elemento por id `getElementById('CuentasHeaderListUpdateForm')`, ¿cual se supone que debería seleccionar, si hay muchos con la misma id?. Si vas a crear muchos forms, dales una id única a cada uno. Puedes concatenarle a la id que le diste el [$loop->iterartor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#the-loop-variable) o algo que genere una id distinta en cada loop del foreach

Comment: lol en realidad lo intente y recien funciono, podrias poner tu comentario en respuestas para que aceptarla? gracias!! :D

Comment: Ah genial! Fué solo una sugerencia, supongo que la respuesta la encontraste vos probando. Si te parece bien [escribe una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) explicando como lo lograste, así queda para toda la comunidad ;)